# Communictaion between TFLuna and Arduino MKR WiFi 1010 won't work

Tags: sensors, i2c, lidar, arduino-mkr1000

I am trying to set up a conncetion between my TFLuna sensor and my Arduino MKR Board.

For this I am using the given example of the TFMPlus Library. All Pins should be connected to the right Inputs.

But for refernce:

TFLUNA | Arduino MKR 1010
Pin 1 | 5V
Pin 2 | RX
Pin 3 | TX
Pin 4 | GND

The code I am using is the standard example, my only concern is, that it is plotting nothing to console. But that is normal using printf right?

```cpp
/* File Name: TFMP_example.ino
 * Developer: Bud Ryerson
 * Inception: 29JAN2019
 * Last work: 10SEP2021

 * Description: Arduino sketch to test the Benewake TFMini Plus
 * time-of-flight Lidar ranging sensor using the TFMPlus Library.

 * Default settings for the TFMini Plus are a 115200 serial baud rate
 * and a 100Hz measurement frame rate. The device will begin returning
 * measurement data right away:
 *   Distance in centimeters,
 *   Signal strength in arbitrary units,
 *   and an encoded number for Temperature in degrees centigrade.

 * Use the 'sendCommand()' to send commands and return a status code.
 * Commands are selected from the library's list of defined commands.
 * Parameters can be entered directly (115200, 250, etc) but for
 * safety, they should be chosen from the library's defined lists.
 */

#include <TFMPlus.h>  // Include TFMini Plus Library v1.5.0
TFMPlus tfmP;         // Create a TFMini Plus object

#include "printf.h"   // Modified to support Intel based Arduino
                      // devices such as the Galileo. Download from:
                      // https://github.com/spaniakos/AES/blob/master/printf.h

// The Software Serial library is an alternative for devices that
// have only one hardware serial port. Delete the comment slashes
// on lines 37 and 38 to invoke the library, and be sure to choose
// the correct RX and TX pins: pins 10 and 11 in this example. Then
// in the 'setup' section, change the name of the hardware 'Serial2'
// port to match the name of your software serial port, such as:
// 'mySerial.begin(115200); etc.

//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>       
//SoftwareSerial mySerial( 10, 11);   
                                    
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin( 4800);   // Intialize terminal serial port
    delay(20);               // Give port time to initalize
    while(!Serial);
    printf_begin();          // Initialize printf.
    Serial.println("Hello world");
    
    printf("\r\nTFMPlus Library Example - 10SEP2021\r\n");  // say 'hello'

    Serial2.begin( 9600); 
    while(!Serial2); // Initialize TFMPLus device serial port.
    delay(20);               // Give port time to initalize
    tfmP.begin( &Serial2);   // Initialize device library object and...
                             // pass device serial port to the object.

    // Send some example commands to the TFMini-Plus
    // - - Perform a system reset - - - - - - - - - - -
    printf( "Soft reset: ");
    if( tfmP.sendCommand( SOFT_RESET, 0))
    {
        printf( "passed.\r\n");
    }
    else tfmP.printReply();
  
    delay(500);  // added to allow the System Rest enough time to complete

  // - - Display the firmware version - - - - - - - - -
    printf( "Firmware version: ");
    if( tfmP.sendCommand( GET_FIRMWARE_VERSION, 0))
    {
        printf( "%1u.", tfmP.version[ 0]); // print three single numbers
        printf( "%1u.", tfmP.version[ 1]); // each separated by a dot
        printf( "%1u\r\n", tfmP.version[ 2]);
    }
    else tfmP.printReply();
    // - - Set the data frame-rate to 20Hz - - - - - - - -
    printf( "Data-Frame rate: ");
    if( tfmP.sendCommand( SET_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_20))
    {
        printf( "%2uHz.\r\n", FRAME_20);
    }
    else tfmP.printReply();
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

/*  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  
    // The next two commands may be used to switch the device 
    // into I2C mode.  This sketch will no longer receive UART
    // (serial) data.  The 'TFMPI2C_example' sketch in the 
    // TFMPI2C Library can be used to switch the device back
    // to UART mode.
    // Don't forget to switch the cables, too.
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    printf( "Set I2C Mode: ");
    if( tfmP.sendCommand( SET_I2C_MODE, 0))
    {
        printf( "mode set.\r\n");
    }
    else tfmP.printReply();
    printf( "Save settings: ");
    if( tfmP.sendCommand( SAVE_SETTINGS, 0))
    {
        printf( "saved.\r\n");
    }
    else tfmP.printReply();
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -    
*/

  delay(500);            // And wait for half a second.
}

// Initialize variables
int16_t tfDist = 0;    // Distance to object in centimeters
int16_t tfFlux = 0;    // Strength or quality of return signal
int16_t tfTemp = 0;    // Internal temperature of Lidar sensor chip

// Use the 'getData' function to pass back device data.
void loop()
{
    delay(20);   // Loop delay to match the 20Hz data frame rate

    if( tfmP.getData( tfDist, tfFlux, tfTemp)) // Get data from the device.
    {
      printf( "Dist:%04icm ", tfDist);   // display distance,
      printf( "Flux:%05i ",   tfFlux);   // display signal strength/quality,
      printf( "Temp:%2i%s",  tfTemp, "C");   // display temperature,
      printf( "\r\n");                   // end-of-line.
    }
    else                  // If the command fails...
    {
      tfmP.printFrame();  // display the error and HEX dataa
    }
}
```

This code should be working with Arduino UNO as seen in multiple examples but what do I need to change for Arduino MKR? Shouldn't it be a pretty similar architecture?

Can someone help me out here?

I tried several baud rates and also I2C conection but I couldn't get it going. The only response  I receive on the serial monitor is:

Status: HEADER
Data: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

or as for I2C:
Status: I2C-WRITE